# Shell command not as expected

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins Pipelines/Groovy and am struggling with the following:

```
stage('Gating') {
    def gatingBaseUrl = "https://www.gating.org/api"

    def gatingParams = [
        "fiability": "$MIN_FIABILITY", 
        "security": "$MIN_SECURITY", 
        "maintenability": "$MIN_MAINTENABILITY"
    ]
    
    gatingQueryParams = gatingParams.collect{ k,v -> "$k=$v" }.join('&')
    gatingUrl = gatingBaseUrl + '?' + gatingQueryParams
    
    println "gatingUrl: " + gatingUrl

    sh(script: "echo $gatingUrl", returnStdout: true)
 }
```

Outputs something like this:

```
[Pipeline] echo
gatingUrl: https://www.gating.org/api?fiability=A&security=A&maintenability=A
[Pipeline] sh
+ maintenability=A
+ echo 'https://www.gating.org/api?fiability=A&security=A&maintenability=A'
+ security=A
```

I am trying to figure out why my url is splitted when used in shell and how do I fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `&` in bash or shell has a different meaning. I found a good [guide](https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html) for that - take a look.
To solve your problem just replace `&` with `\\&` escape sequence, it should work. Like below.

```
 sh(script: "echo ${gatingUrl.replace('&','\\&')}", returnStdout: true)
```

or

```
sh "echo ${gatingUrl.replace('&','\\&')}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I just change my join clause to .join("\\&") and it resolved the issue. Your awnser makes total sense but I was confused do to fact that the code I started with worked and was built like the following:
 gatingUrl = "$gatingBaseUrl?fiability=$MIN_FIABILITY'&'security=$MIN_SECURITY'&'maintenabilitY=$MIN_MAINTENABILITY

Comment: Escape sequence \\& will work for shell , but not for groovy. Hence do that replace only in sh